# How to score for claiming routes in Ticket to Ride: Europe

Tags: ticket-to-ride, scoring, ticket-to-ride-europe

Apologies if this is answered somewhere. I haven’t found it.

I have a couple of questions as a new player to Ticket to Ride Europe.

1. How many points do you score if the route you claim does not match the scoring table e.g. 5, 7, 9+ trains to create a route across multiple stations? I read somewhere that a 5 train route = 10pts but elsewhere that this has been removed on the Europe edition. If removed then I don’t understand if it means you can’t claim a 5 train route e.g. 4 + 1 or you just have to take the points for 4 trains even though putting down 5. And earlier I put down 12 trains in one go but had no idea how to score it. The rules don’t mention anything about scoring routes that don’t match the table. And you must be able to go across multiple stations in one go as there are no 8 train routes that don’t go across a station in between.
2. I assume this isn’t possible and needs to be done in 2 turns, but wanted to check... if I have a route already claimed, am I able to add another route at the beginning of it and a route at the end of it in one turn since it creates one continuous route? If so, how is it scored?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you have some misunderstandings regarding how to play Ticket To Ride: Europe. You cannot ever claim more than one route in your turn.

You can do one, and only one, of these actions in your turn From [the Rulebook,](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/te_rules_2015_en.pdf) page 3:

> On his turn, a player must perform one
>   **(and only one)** of the following four actions:
>
> - **Draw Train Car Cards:** The player may draw two Train cards (or just
>     one, if the card he selects is a face-up Locomotive. See Locomotives
>     for special rules);
> - **Claim a Route**: The player claims **a** route on the
>     board by playing a set of Train cards from his hand that match the
>     color and quantity of the spaces that make up the route. He places
>     one of his colored trains on each space, and scores the number of
>     points indicated on the Route Scoring Table for that route’s length;
> - **Draw Destination Tickets**: The player draws three Destination Tickets
>     from the top of the Tickets deck, and must keep at least one of them;
> - **Build a Train Station**: – The player may build a Station in any city
>     that does not yet have one. To build his first Train Station, the
>     player plays one Train card of any color and places one of his Train
>     Stations on that city. To build his second station, a player must
>     play a set of two cards of the same color, and to build his third
>     station a set of three cards of the same color

There is actually a route of 8 spaces, it's the tunnel between Stockholm and Petrograd.

On defining a route, page 4:

> A route is a set of continuous colored spaces (in some instances, gray
>   spaces) **between two adjacent cities on the map**. To claim a route, a player
>   must play a set of Train cards whose color and quantity match the color
>   and number of spaces of the chosen route.

There are no 5 train routes in TTR: Europe, so that's why there's no scoring for that number. So both 1) and 2) on your question aren't possible.

On scoring, page 7:

> When a player claims a route, he immediately scores the number of points indicated
>   on the Route Scoring Table for the length of the route he just claimed.

You score immediately for the size of the route you claimed, and since you can only claim one route, you can score only within the table.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be misunderstanding a key part of how the game works, in both Ticket to Ride Europe and regular Ticket to Ride.

On a single turn, you can only put down enough trains to follow a single path between adjacent cities. You cannot go through multiple cities at once.

So a route of length 8 for 21 points is the longest route you can claim. On later turns, you can claim another route, whether it is adjacent to one you have already claimed or not.

From [the rules](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/te_rules_2015_en.pdf):

> A route is a set of continuous colored spaces (in some instances, gray spaces) between two adjacent cities on the map. To claim a route, a player must play a set of Train cards whose color and quantity match the color and number of spaces of the chosen route.
>
> Most routes require a specific set of colored cards to claim them. Locomotives can always act as a stand-in for any given color (See example 1).
>
> Routes that are Gray can be claimed using a set of cards of any one color (See example 2).

Regular Ticket to Ride has some routes that are length 5 and are worth 10 points, but Ticket to Ride Europe does not have any routes of length 5 on the board.